# How to switch from -R 777 to -R755

Tags: laravel, permission-denied

I just created a laravel project and when i tried to access the public directory, i got this error:

```
Failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

After 1h of reading questions, i made it using `chmod -R 777 storage`

The problem is that i read that 777 it's not safe, so 755 or 644 it's recommaned, but when i try to switch from 777 to 644, i get this error in browser(when trying to access the public dir again):

```
There is no existing directory at "/opt/lampp/htdocs/msi/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Permission denied
```

and when i try to switch from 777 to 755, i get this in terminal:

```
chmod: Unable to change file mode on storage/framework/views/a8c3ac09807ed92953f9291bafad88c01bafca30.php: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on storage/framework/sessions/oGFGq02UR5jhT1YTaNJWxmpSzrsrC4TzAlI9LeoN: Operation not permitted
```

I'm on macOS and i'm using XAMPP, if this is an important information.

Edit: I solve it by changing xampp with mamp.I don't know what was the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `sudo chmod -R 755 storage`?

Comment: yes, and i get this: chmod: Unable to change file mode on storage/framework/views/a8c3ac09807ed92953f9291bafad88c01bafca30.php: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on storage/framework/sessions/oGFGq02UR5jhT1YTaNJWxmpSzrsrC4TzAlI9LeoN: Operation not permitted

Comment: I don't see why using `sudo` wouldn't allow you to change the permissions. Are you able to delete those files and try again?

Answer (score 0):

try these two permissions after installation of laravel project.i hope it will help you.

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R 0777 storage
```

Comment: chmod: bootstrap/cache: No such file or directory